# Pandas: Add new columns using iterative values of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with 2 columns - one with the words and the other with the pos_tags.

```
       word1  tag1
0        Why  WRB
1         is  VBZ
2       this   DT
3  happening   NN
4         to   TO
5         us  PRP
6    Asterix  NNP
7        and   CC
8     Obelix  NNP
```

How do I add two more columns whose values are the (i+1)th values of columns 'word1' & 'tag1' to result in;

```
       word1  tag1       word2   tag2
0        Why   WRB          is    VBZ
1         is   VBZ        this     DT
2       this    DT   happening    NNP
3  happening   NNP         to      TO
4         to    TO          us    PRP
5         us   PRP     Asterix    NNP
6    Asterix   NNP         and     CC
7        and    CC      Obelix    NNP
8     Obelix   NNP         nan    nan
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `shift(-1)` on the dataframe

```
In [109]: df[['word2', 'tag2']] = df.shift(-1)

In [110]: df
Out[110]:
       word1 tag1      word2 tag2
0        Why  WRB         is  VBZ
1         is  VBZ       this   DT
2       this   DT  happening   NN
3  happening   NN         to   TO
4         to   TO         us  PRP
5         us  PRP    Asterix  NNP
6    Asterix  NNP        and   CC
7        and   CC     Obelix  NNP
8     Obelix  NNP        NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the new columns by calling [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift) and pass `-1` as the interval:

```
In [84]:

df['word2'], df['tag2'] = df['word1'].shift(-1), df['tag1'].shift(-1)
df
Out[84]:
       word1 tag1      word2 tag2
0        Why  WRB         is  VBZ
1         is  VBZ       this   DT
2       this   DT  happening   NN
3  happening   NN         to   TO
4         to   TO         us  PRP
5         us  PRP    Asterix  NNP
6    Asterix  NNP        and   CC
7        and   CC     Obelix  NNP
8     Obelix  NNP        NaN  NaN
```